# Finding mean-square convergence of a stochastic process

Tags: limits, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Given a process:
$$ X_t = (1-t)\int_0^t \frac{1}{1-s} dB_s $$ I am asked to prove the existence of the $L^2$ limit as $t\rightarrow 1^- $ $\mathbb{P}$-a.s. and to calculate this limit. How would you go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$EX_t^{2}=(1-t)^{2}\int_0^{t}  \frac 1 {(1-s)^{2}}ds=(1-t)^{2}(\frac  1  {1-t}-1)=1-t-(1-t)^{2}\to 0$. Hence $L^{2}$ limit is $0$.